# missing modeling perspective with UML Designer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml-designer

When running Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) with UML-Designer (7.1), I cannot find any Modeling perspective.
Could this be a bug or an Eclipse configuration issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your configuration, Eclipse Neon 2 with UML Designer 7.1 installed,  and it works just fine.
To switch to the `Modeling Perspective`, you can select `Open Perspective` 
[image]
And then in the dialog select the `Modeling` one.
[image]

Comment: An Eclipse error is reported:
_java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available_.
Reinstalling Eclipse has fixed this issue.
Thanks